# Using various inequalities to prove this martingale inequality?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations, local-martingales

I’ve got another martingale inequality that I would be grateful for a kickstart on.

> Suppose $X_t$ is a local martingale such that $|X_t|$ and $\langle X_t\rangle\leq c$ $\forall$ $t\geq 0$ and for some constant
> $c\in\mathbb R$. I need to show that $$\mathbb{E}\left(\sup_{t\geq
>  0}X_t\right)^4\leq361\mathbb{E}\langle X\rangle_\infty^2.$$

How should I approach this? I asked a question of similar nature previously, so I suspect I will need Cauchy-Schwarz's, Doob's, and Grönwall's inequalities here. However, in the previous question, $X_t$ was given in SDE form, so applying the inequalities made sense — here, all I know is that it is a martingale, so I'm not too sure where to start. Please guide me, thank you!

Comment: Can you attach a link to the question of similar nature previously asked?

Comment: The inequality is a particular case of the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality.

Comment: @saz hi, I just took a look at the inequality — it’s not very illuminating to me, where do the constant on both sides of the equation come from? i can understand it for p=2 but for a general p (as well as this case) what would be the course of action?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon hi, the question I asked is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3854669/320332

Comment: @user107224 Noted. As mentioned, your inequality is a case of the BDG inequality. However, I will see if I can present a proof specific to this case.

Comment: @user107224:  Is $\{X_t \}$ a continuous local martingale such that $X_0=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $X$ is a continuous local martingale such that $X_0=0$ and that $\langle X \rangle$ is the quadratic variation process of $X.$

Applying Ito's formula with $f(x)=x^4$ we have
$$|X_t|^4 = 4 \int_0^t X_t^3 dX_t + 6 \int_0^t X_t^2 d\langle X \rangle_t. \tag{1}$$

Since $X$ is bounded, $E \int_0^t|X_s|^6ds < \infty,$ so the process $\{ \int_0^t X^3_s dX_s, t \geq 0 \}$ is a martingale and therefore, $E \int_0^t X^3_s dX_s = 0.$

Thus, taking expectations in (1)
$$E|X_t|^4 \leq 6 E[\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} |X_s|^2 \langle X \rangle_t]$$
and by the Holder inequality
$$E|X_t|^4 \leq 6 \left(E\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} |X_s|^4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(E\langle X \rangle^2_t \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}. \tag{2}$$
Now (apart from the above) by Doob's martingale inequality
$$E \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t}|X_s|^4 \leq \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^4 E|X_t|^4. \tag{3}$$
Substituting (2) in (3)
$$E \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t}|X_s|^4 \leq \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^4 6 \left(E\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} |X_s|^4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(E\langle X \rangle^2_t \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
Thus
$$E \left( \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t}X_s \right)^4 \leq E \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t}|X_s|^4 \leq \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^8 6^2  E\langle X \rangle^2_t.$$

Comment: beautiful solution! thank you!

Comment: just a quick general question — when are the absolute values necessary? usually for ito’s formula I hardly see absolute values put into place, plus the RHS if the first line doesn’t involve any, which confuses me slightly.

Comment: @user107224:  since $X^4_t \geq 0,$ they are not necessary.

Comment: another quick general question — is the line about the integral of X^3 wrt dX an isometry argument? Is there a general statement about the expectation of (the powers of) bounded martingales?

Comment: also for the last line, should the first $\leq$ be an = since the supremum of a set of the squares of non-negative numbers is equal to the square of the supremum?

Comment: see the edit for the first question. It's not related with the Ito isometry, it's because the integral (as a process) is a martingale and a martingale has constant expectation.

Comment: For the second question, the $\leq$ is correct, but if you prefer to put an $"="$ is also fine. It doesn't change the result anyway. The reason why I didn't wrote $"="$ is because you have to prove prove that the supremum is always going to be positive (which is the case because $X$ is a martingale that starts at $0$. However, the way I wrote it, I don't need to say anything about that and it's still correct.

Comment: I’m starting to overthink and worry about the martingale property now. Is the lebesgue integral of X_s^6 < infty because X_s is bounded, or because the quadratic variation is bounded? Likewise, is the Ito integral of X^3 a martingale because it is L2 bounded due to bounded quadratic variation? if you could explain a bit more about it that would be awesome!

Comment: first question: because $X$ is bounded. Second question: have a look at my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473273/to-show-martingale-what-other-conditions-do-you-need-to-check-if-the-process-ha/3473689#3473689